# how to put stream php://temp content to html

Tags: php, html, stream, guzzle, php-stream-wrappers

I got this from the API which is audio if I try it in postman.

[image]

the problem is I don't know how to retrieve it and put it in audio in html. I try to put the php://temp in src in audio html but it not work. because I used guzzle I try to use `$response->getBody()->getContents()` and I think it's the same as file_get_contents() in php but it shows nothing when I print it. please help in postman it can work but I don't know how to get it.

Comment: Try `(string)$resp->getBody();` - if it's empty, it's empty. I haven't done much work with audio though

Comment: yes I already try it it's not empty but it string so I don't know how to make it to the audio html or play the audio

Comment: You could potentially stream it from the src configured in `<audio>`. Might be easier to save that contents into an audio file on your system though

Comment: didn't you just ask a similar question

Comment: sorry I ask in different way that may be someone understand but I just got the answer in my old question

Answer (score 0):

well in the lastest guzzlehttp document.you should iterate the body like this

```php
$body = $response->getBody();
while (!$body->eof()) {
    echo $body->read(1024);
}
```

or better way save stream response to file

```php
$body = $response->getBody();
file_put_contents('/webroot/file.mp3',$body);
```

then set html src

```html
<audio src="file.mp3"></audio>
```

Comment: I try the while but it echo nothing and I also try with file_put_contents and when I var_dump it it says int(23596). is there something wrong?

Comment: dose the file contain something?